# Сборка C программы в Sublime 3

Tags: c, sublime-text, mingw

На другом компьютере настраивал в своё время компилятор для работы с Sublime 3. Сейчас на новом устройстве скачал Sublime и настроил компилятор и пытаюсь запустить свои старые программы, которые до этого запускались, сейчас же выскочили ошибки. Суть ошибок мне ясна, но не очень получается исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, а как вы пытались исправить ошибки, если вам ясна их суть?

Comment: Где вы взяли компилятор?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте флаг `-std=c99` или `-std=c11` в опции компилятора. Вам даже сам компилятор об этом говорит: «*note: use option `-std=c99`, `-std=gnu99`, `-std=c11` or -`std=gnu11` to compile your code*».